# Does Sliced Wasserstein Distance work in higher than 2 dimensions?

Tags: autoencoder, distance, wasserstein

I had thought that it only worked for 2D distributions.
I am trying to implement a sliced Wasserstein autoencoder and I was wondering if my latent space can be larger than 2D.